# i18next not loading files in backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, internationalization, i18next

Hi I am using i18next in my Node JS Application.
The following is the config code for i18next:

```
const i18nextBackend = require('i18next-node-fs-backend');

 i18n
  .use(i18nextBackend)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,
    backend: {
      loadPath: 'locales/{{lng}}.json',
      addPath: 'locales/{{lng}}.json',
      jsonIndent: 2,
    },
  }, (err, t) => {
    // init set content
    console.log(t);
    // console.log('INIT DONE');
  });
  console.log(i18n.t('hello'));
```

I have en.js in my locales folder in which JSON format data is there. But the file is unable to load. Can anybody tell how to give the path name in loadPath properly?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you did not add a backend plugin at all. https://github.com/i18next/i18next-node-fs-backend filesystem backend might be what you search

Comment: I have edited by adding a backend plugin. But the error is still there and error is : Uncaught TypeError: _fs2.default.readFile is not a function

Comment: Can you give me a small example where I can understand the working of getting data from files.

Comment: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-express-middleware/blob/master/examples/basic-pug/index.js#L10 there are full samples in the repo